# Realm : Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred

Tags: realm

I'm trying to use "Realm" with a few lines of code found on "stackoverflow".
I get an enigmatic compilation error:
Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred
on the line: let dogs = List<Dog>()
every time I use List<> this error appears.

I've tried everything, cleaning up the build, quitting xcode, starting again from scratch with a new project, but there's still this error...

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

class Dog: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var age = 0
}

class Person: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    let dogs = List<Dog>()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("toto")
                .onAppear {
                    
                    let myDog = Dog()
                    myDog.name = "Rex"
                    myDog.age = 5
                    hop(myDog: myDog)
                }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func hop(myDog: Dog) {
        let realm = try! Realm() 
        
        let person = Person()
        person.name = "Tim"
        person.dogs.append(myDog) 
        
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(person) 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the Realm + SwiftUI documentation there is an entirely different setup

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

The first thing is intermixing @objc with Swift; there's no reason to do that (in fact, don't). Stick with Swift syntax as this point.

So the two Realm models should be this

```
class Dog: Object {
    @Persisted var name = ""
    @Persisted var age = 0
}

class Person: Object {
    @Persisted var name = ""
    @Persisted var dogs = RealmSwift.List<Dog>() //specify RealmSwift here*
}
```

The second thing is in the `.onAppear` function - whenever .onAppear is called, a dog object will be instantiated, a person object will be instantiated and both will be written to Realm. The end result over time is you'll have a database full of Tim's and Rex's and that's probably not what you want.

Lastly, Realm has a number of other language features with SwiftUI. I suggest reviewing the [Realm with SwiftUI Quickstart](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui-tutorial/) to familiarize yourself with some of the other features it has. Nothing wrong with your code in that respect but you can leverage SwiftUI in other ways as well.

*`RealmSwift.List` needs to be implicitly used here to avoid a name collision with SwiftUI's `List`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very clear comment. It is perfect !

Comment: @Rocou My pleasure - glad it helped! Be sure to accept the answer so it can help others as well. See [How to Accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)